# how to serialize a json date time to joda-time

Tags: java, json, playframework, jodatime

this is the exception i have during my parsing my payload from client
Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class org.joda.time.DateTime] from String value ('2014-06-18 06:26:56-07:00'); no single-String constructor/factory method

because since there's no arguements for the joda-time that accepts a string date

this my json payload from (client/web), model and controller

payload

```
[
  {
    "id": 10000000,
    "name": "Dimebad Darrel",
    "duetime": "2014-06-18 06:26:56-07:00",
    "jointime": "2015-04-08 12:47:16-07:00"
  }
]
```

Customer.class

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable, Comparable<Customer>{

    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
    //@JsonSerialize(using = DateSerializer.class)
    private DateTime duetime;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
    //@JsonSerialize(using = DateSerializer.class)
    private DateTime jointime;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public DateTime getDuetime() {
        return duetime;
    }

    public void setDuetime(DateTime duetime) {
        // String startDate = "2013-07-12T18:31:01.000Z";
        // DateTime dt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().parseDateTime(startDate); 
        this.duetime = duetime;
    }

    public DateTime getJointime() {
        return jointime;
    }

    public void setJointime(DateTime jointime) {
        this.jointime = jointime;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Customer customer) {
        DateTime thisDueDate = customer.getDuetime();
        DateTime otherDueDate = customer.getDuetime();

        if( thisDueDate.isAfter(otherDueDate) )
            return 1;
        else if( thisDueDate.isBefore(otherDueDate) )
            return -1;
        // default equals   
        return 0;
    }

}
```

CustomerController.class

```
public class CustomerController extends Controller{

    @Inject
    CustomerService service;

    public Result sortCustomer() {
        try{
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

            Json.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
            String jsonString = request().body().asJson().toString();
            List<Customer> customers = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString,
                            objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Customer.class));

            //service.sort( customers );

            return ok( Json.toJson(customers) );
        }catch(Exception ex ){
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [jackson-datatype-joda](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda)

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
```

Comment: Configure mapper registering module, that's what I was missing! Thank you!